# C programming : dereferencing pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I have these three files. using structures, functions and pointers.

Trying to do this:

**`void getName(Name *)` - Receives a pointer to a Name and performs the actions**

contacts.h

```
struct Name {
char firstName[31];
char middleInitial[7];
char lastName[36];
};
struct Contacts {
struct Name name;
struct Address address;
struct Numbers numbers;
};
void getName(struct Name*name);
```

contacts.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "contacts.h"

void getName(struct Name*name)
{
    char yorn;
        printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
scanf("%s", name->firstName);

printf("Do you want to enter a middle initial(s)? (y or n): ");
scanf("%s", &yorn);

if (yorn == 'y'){
    printf("Please enter the contact's middle initial(s): ");
    scanf("%s", name->middleInitial);
}

printf("Please enter the contact's last name: ");
scanf("%s", name->lastName);
}
```

a1ms4.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "contacts.h"
#include "contacts.c"

struct Name name;
getName(&contact.name);
```

I'm getting the following error in contacts.c:

error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type struct Name

`scanf("%s", name->firstName);`

```
                 ^~
```

[EDIT:
I minimized the code to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Name {
char firstName[31];
};

struct Contacts {

struct Name name;
};

void getName(Name*name);

int main(void)
{

struct Contacts contact;
getName(&contact.name);
return 0;
}

void getName(Name*name)
{
char yorn;
printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
scanf("%c", name->firstName);

printf("First name: %c\n", name.firstName);

return;
}
```

and getting these error:

1). error: unknown type name â`Name`â

`void getName(Name*name);`

2). In function â`main`â:

warning: implicit declaration of function â`getName`â; did you mean â`getline`â? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

`getName(&contact.name);`

3). At top level:

error: unknown type name â`Name`â

`void getName(Name*name)`

Comment: Don't include `*.c` files! Ever. Until you are a pro and know *exactly* what you are doing.

Comment: This is an assignment and they wanted us to include all three files

Comment: The error is clear: You cannot use the type Name if it is incomplete. Since you already fully declared Name in the header contacts.h, you can remove the pre-declaration entirely.

Comment: No way they are asking such a thing. If they are - I would reconsider studying C in this place.

Comment: @SaM Eugene is right, c files should never be included. c files should be compiled and linked (and in that sense, included into your output executable project)

Comment: You should have gotten numerous redefinition errors with this code.

Comment: Yes I understand that I should not include the `*.c` files.

Comment: But what changes should I make to fix this error?

Comment: What errors do you get when you actually remove this include? All of them. BTW, looks like the function call is happening outside of `main`. Please provide [mcve] after fixed the errors mentioned.

Comment: Where is `contact` in a1ms4.c declared?

Comment: Do you think using `scanf("%s"` with a `char` variable address is a good idea? Read how `scanf` works carefully...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes I minimized the code and posted below if you could please take a look thanks

Comment: @NetMage Yes I know it should be %c its just there were few error due to that but now i changed it

Comment: @NetMage I just reposted the program below and put it into one main file if you could take a look thanks

Comment: @StarShine I just reposted the program below and put it into one main file if you could take a look thanks

Comment: @EugeneSh. Okay I posted it in the question section now. and typed `typedef` with the function but still no luck

Comment: It's difficult to understand what the question is at this point. I assume the errors at the end of the post is what you are asking about. I see two problems: C reads the file from the top, so anything you define and then use has to be defined before it is used, in the file, and when you define a struct you get a struct, not a new type.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `struct Foo {...};` in C, you are not defining a type with the name `Foo`. Instead, you are defining a `struct` by the name `Foo` **which is referenced as `struct Foo`.

Thus, when you say `void getName(Name*name);`, your compiler rightly complains that there is no type called `Name`. Since it could not parse this function declaration, it subsequently complains about not knowing about that function when you call it. Ignore that second error, it's not your problem. Fix the prototype.

---

There are two methods of fixing your program:

1. Call your structs `struct`. At each and every instance where you have `Name` in your code, ensure that you are actually saying `struct Name` instead.
2. Write a `typedef` that defines the type `Name`. Declare your struct like this:

   ```
   struct Foo { ... };
   typedef struct Foo Foo;
   ```

   Since C programmers are lazy gits, they will usually merge these two statements into the following declaration:

   ```
   typedef struct Foo { ... } Foo;
   ```

   This declares both the `struct Foo` and its alias `Foo` in a single statement. You'll see this a lot in real code.

---

The form of the typedef deserves some explanation. I find it easiest to think of it as a variable declaration with `typedef` prepended to turn the variable name into a type name. I.e. if you can declare an array of strings with

```
char* array[10];
```

then you can give a name to its type with

```
typedef char* ArrayType[10];
```

After that, you can declare the above array with a simple

```
ArrayType array;
```

So, when you say

```
typedef struct Foo Foo;
```

the second `Foo` is the name that is being declared, and the type it aliases is the rest of the declaration without the `typedef`: `struct Foo`.

Comment: Yes I got it Thank You it fixed the error of unknown type. I put `struct` before the Name in the function. really appreciate the help

Comment: It is giving the error: request for member `firstName` in something not a structure or union

Comment: @SaM Ah, overlooked that mistake: When `firstName` is a pointer (declared with `struct Name* firsName`), you cannot use the `.` operator to access its members. You must use the dereferencing `->` operator instead.

Comment: Now I am gonna try and put it separately in `*.h` `*.c` and `main`

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things wrong but I think your main error is that you have declared `Name` as `struct Name` so you need to use `struct Name` instead of just `Name`.

Comment: Yes I put that `Struct` before the Name and its working now. Thank you for help.
There is this new error: request for member `firstName` in something not a structure or union

Comment: I put every code in place (`*.h` `*.c` `main`) and now I am getting two kinds of errors in the header file
one is Conflicting type with the get*
second is redefination of struct *

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing a pointer means using the * operator to access the value stored at a pointer. But keep it in mind that the value stored at the address of the pointer must be a value of the same type as the type of variable the pointer "points" to, but there is no guarantee this is the case unless the pointer was set correctly.